# R, Numbering unique and duplicated values in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is in chronological order that shows chess matches and results. I want to add a new column that will give me the match number of a particular individual as you go down the data frame.

```
 Player <- c("Joe", "Bill", "Chris","Bill","Joe","Mark")
 Opponent <- c("Bill", "Joe", "Bill","Chris","Mark","Joe")
 Outcome <- c("W", "L", "W", "L", "L", "W")
 GameNumber <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)

 Results <- data.frame(Player, Opponent, Outcome, GameNumber)
```

The Current table looks like this

```
 Player Opponent Outcome GameNumber
 Joe    Bill     W       1
 Bill   Joe      L       1
 Chris  Bill     W       2
 Bill   Chris    L       2
 Joe    Mark     L       3
 Mark   Joe      W       3
```

However I would like to add a new column which give the match number for the particular player i.e

```
 Player Opponent Outcome GameNumber PlayerMatchNumber
 Joe    Bill     W       1          1
 Bill   Joe      L       1          1
 Chris  Bill     W       2          1
 Bill   Chris    L       2          2
 Joe    Mark     L       3          2
 Mark   Joe      W       3          1
```

As it would be Bill's 2nd match in his contest vs Chris as it would be for Joe in his vs Mark.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you  get these numbers?

Comment: Please clarify how you calculate the new column `PlayerMatchNumber`.

Comment: Each Game has 2 rows attached with it. So the Game Joe vs Bill is the same Game as Bill vs Joe thats way the GameNumber is the same and Joe Wins and Bill Loses. It would be each their first game, but when Chris plays Bill in the GameNumber 2 it would be Bill's 2nd game therefore the PlayerMatchNumber is 2 for Bill, but 1 for Chris as it is his 1st Game

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `data.table`:-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Results)
Results[, PlayerMatchNumber := 1:.N, by = Player]
```

You'll get output :-

```
     Player Opponent Outcome GameNumber PlayerMatchNumber
1:    Joe     Bill       W          1                 1
2:   Bill      Joe       L          1                 1
3:  Chris     Bill       W          2                 1
4:   Bill    Chris       L          2                 2
5:    Joe     Mark       L          3                 2
6:   Mark      Joe       W          3                 1
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty base version

```
Results$PlayerMatchNumber <- rowSums(sapply(unique(Results$Player), function(x) 
  cumsum(x == Results$Player) * as.numeric(x == Results$Player)))


Results$PlayerMatchNumber
# 1 1 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` one can:

```
library(dplyr)

Results %>% 
  group_by(Player) %>% 
  mutate(Number = seq_along(Player)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# Player Opponent Outcome GameNumber Number
# <fctr> <fctr>   <fctr>       <dbl>  <int>
# 1 Joe    Bill     W             1.00      1
# 2 Bill   Joe      L             1.00      1
# 3 Chris  Bill     W             2.00      1
# 4 Bill   Chris    L             2.00      2
# 5 Joe    Mark     L             3.00      2
# 6 Mark   Joe      W             3.00      1
```